# How can I config the floating IP to a public ip in OpenStack?

Tags: ip, openstack, floating-ip

In the dashboard:

Under the Project -> Compute -> Instances:

I created a instance, named test02, and its IP address is `10.0.0.7` and the floating IP is `172.24.4.12`. I want to know can I config the floating IP to a public IP, so that it's accessible to the public network.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have deployed an instance with private and public (floating IP) interfaces. I could see the floating IP is assigned to your instance.
Please confirm if there is any public network (172.24.4.0) in your openstack network environment, and did you configured neutron-bridge interface?

If so, you can access the instance from outside network using (172.24.4.12) IP address.

Comment: The (172.24.4.12) is the local area network, I have some public ip, but how can I config the public ip to there?

Comment: You need to deal with `NAT` on the equipment that have your "really real" public IP address(the one that does not makes part of `RFC1918` of reserved ips)... If it's a firewall, a webcacher or "accelerator" we don't know...

Comment: You can configure a bridging interface in neutron api. Could you brief about installation method of Openstack installation . Devstack installation ??